# Django name 'admin' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm following this tutorial and i have some troubles. 
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tf8XlhsQAo

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^webapp/', include("webapp.urls")),
    url(r'^$',include("personal.urls")),

]
```

I've written the code above, however when I executed I get the error below, can anyone help me understand the meaning of this error message?

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Django\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 24, in <modu
>
    url(r'^$',include("personal.urls")),
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
s\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\
init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Django\mysite\personal\urls.py", line 5, in <mod
e>
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
NameError: name 'admin' is not defined
```

Comment: Note that your include should be `url(r'^',include("personal.urls")),` - If you include the dollar then only the root URL `/` will work.

Answer (score 3):

The traceback is telling you that the error is occurring in your `personal\urls.py` file:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Django\mysite\personal\urls.py", line 5, in <mode>
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
```

You have already included the admin urls in `mysite\urls.py`,
you should not include the admin urls in `personal\urls.py`. Remove that line from `personal\urls.py`.

Comment: Thanks. but i have another trouble

Answer (score 1):

The code you have pasted is not having an issue as you are importing the admin.

The code in your personal/urls.py have

```
url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
```

Notice the difference of space between the your code and traceback.

You don't need that line on app's urls.py. Just delete it and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

> File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Django\mysite\personal\urls.py", line 5, in 
>       url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
>   NameError: name 'admin' is not defined
>
> can anyone help me understand the meaning of this error message?

Yes : it tells you that in line 5 of file C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Django\mysite\personal\urls.py - which is `url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),` - you are refering to the variable ("name") `admin`, which has not been defined at this point in this file. IOW, you're trying to use an inexistant variable.

As Alasdaïr and Rahul already mentionned, since you already included the `admin.urls` in your root urlconfig (which is the standard setup), you don't need it here so the obvious solution is to just remove this line - specially since you're including `personal.urls` at your site's top-level so both configs would point to the same url.

But if you wanted to use the `admin` module in `personal.urls` for any other reason - or include it from `personal.urls` instead of your root urlconfig -, you'd need to explicitely import the `admin` module at the top of `personal.urls` - Python's "import" is nothing like PHP's "include" and doesn't magically make a name available to all your project's modules.

Comment: thank you, Can you explain for me a question bellow?

Comment: @PhucCoi don't use answers to ask other questions - this is not a forum or usenet group but a technical Q&A platform. If you have other questions, post a new question instead.