# My Django dont show anything

Tags: python, django

Thank you very much guys! that issue has solved!(Here is my old post [Django name 'admin' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095388/django-name-admin-is-not-defined) )
 but it show nothing. I want to show the content in header.html & home.html

here is the code personal/views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request,'personal/templates/personal/home.html')
```

And here are the code of home and header

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p> Hey welcome to my very first project by Django :D </p>
{% include "personal/includes/"htmlsnippet.html %}
{% endblock %}
```

header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Harry-Phuc Coi</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color: #f6f6f6f6">
    <div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my path
[my path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1QOA.png)

Comment: and urlconfig ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that you should specify the template relative to your templates directory, so you shouldn't need the `personal/templates` prefix.

```
return render(request,'personal/home.html')
```

Secondly you have `"` in the wrong place. It should be at the end of the template name.

```
{% include "personal/includes/htmlsnippet.html" %}
```